# Lowest Possible Average Correlation Between N Random Variables

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, correlation

Suppose $M$ is an $n \times n$ [correlation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence), with correlation $\rho_{i,j}$ between any pair of two random variables. What is the smallest possible average of the $\rho_{i,j}$ where $(i<j)$?

Or in another form what $M$ (class of $M$'s?) minimize

$$\frac{1}{m} \Sigma_{i<j} \, \rho_{i,j}$$

where $m = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.

Can this problem be reduced to this [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2497543/smallest-possible-correlation-between-pair-of-random-variables) for constant correlation matricies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum  possible average correlation is $-1/(n-1)$.

We may assume wlog the random variables all have variance $1$, so the correlations are covariances.  The sum of all covariances (incuding the variances) of $n$ random variables
is $$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \text{Cov}(X_i, X_j) = \text{Cov}\left(\sum_i X_i, \sum_j X_j\right) = \text{Var}\left(\sum_i X_i\right) \ge 0$$
with equality iff $\sum_i X_i$ is almost surely constant.  This can occur with an $n \times n$ covariance matrix having all diagonal elements $1$ and all off-diagonal elements $-1/(n-1)$.  This is positive semidefinite because it has eigenvalues $0$ and $n/(n-1)$ (with multiplicity $n-1$).