# Maximum possible correlation for $N$ random variables sharing idential correlation coefficient

Tags: statistics, upper-lower-bounds, correlation

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ be random variables. For every $i\ne j$, assume $corr(X_i,X_j)=\rho$, where $\rho$ is some constant.

What is the maximum possible value of $\rho$?

Comment: If e.g. $X_1=\cdots=X_n$ then $\rho=1$ and correlation coefficients cannot exceed $1$.

Comment: A more interesting question would be the [minimum possible value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2497543/smallest-possible-correlation-between-pair-of-random-variables) of $\rho$ when $n > 2$